# JavaScript Background Slider to target a div ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to JS and fumbling my way through it.

Does anyone know how to target a specific div ID in order to apply the crossfading background images to just that specific div?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My HTML:

```
<div id="header-background-slider"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
#header-background-slider{
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("/image001.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

My JS:

```
var bgImageArray = ["image001.jpg", "image002.jpg", "image003.jpg"],
base = "/",
secs = 4;
bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
    new Image().src = base + img; 
});

function backgroundSequence() {
    window.clearTimeout();
    var k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.documentElement.style.background = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
            document.documentElement.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
        if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }            
        }, (secs * 1000) * i)   
    }
}
backgroundSequence();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I think is correct, then replace `document.documentElement` with `document.getElementById("header-background-slider")`. Keep the stuff after it. :)

`document.documentElement` targets what is called the "root node". Since you want to target something specific, you can select it from your DOM (Document Object Model) with document.getElementById.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sam. Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: Sam, looks like I was the one to screw up! Your solution worked! Thank you for your help! Much Appreciated!